# Sorting redux store array with sortBy redux action does not send new props to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently trying to build a sortby function which needs to sort an array with venues in the redux store based on alfabetical order. A live demo can be found here: http://tabbs-web-app.herokuapp.com/discover/home

### Paste bins

- [Home.jsx](https://pastebin.com/MbH0tzf8)
- [VenueList.jsx](https://pastebin.com/HAdtR6Eq)
- [VenueListFilter.jsx](https://pastebin.com/MDR93FB4)
- [VenueListItem](https://pastebin.com/3sxtxD2d)
- [Venue Selector / filter function](https://pastebin.com/C58ZsEAd)
- [Filters Action Generactor (redux)](https://pastebin.com/YwPGZ7Fv)
- [Filters Reducer (redux)](https://pastebin.com/a06payCD)

### Description

Unfortunately I am not able to upload the project to codesandbox since it's exceeding the 120 limit modules for sandbox...

The following component is retrieving the array of venues from the API and saves them to the redux store. This component is connected with the redux store and has the following redux functions to filter the array:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    venues: getFilteredVenues(state.venues, state.filters)
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  startSetVenues: () => dispatch(startSetVenues())
});
```

**Home.jsx**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SectionTitle
          title="Discover Nightlife with Tabbs."
          subTitle="Instant jaccess to your favorite nightclubs, lounge, bars and parties
        nationwide."
        />

        <VenueListFilter data={filterOptions} />
        <VenueList data={this.props.venues} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

> The following component is a child component which needs the data from the connected component:

**VenueList.jsx**

```
render({ data } = this.props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid container spacing={8}>
          {data.map((venue, key) => {
            return <VenueListItem key={key} venue={venue} />;
          })}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

> The last component is the individual venue row / object / component:

**VenueListItem.jsx**

```
<Grid item {...rest} className={classes.grid}>
    <ImageCard
      image="https://static.bab.la/pic/living/UK/going-out-dancing.jpg"
      cardTitle={venue.venue_name}
      cardSubtitle={venue.venue_description}
      content="test, abc, def"
    />
  </Grid>
```

### what is the issue I am experiencing right now?

> The redux store is correctly being ordered based on alfabetical order. The mapStateToProps function is being called in the Home.jsx with the correct ordered array. But.. the components render function is not being called again, so the VenueList does not receive the new props / updated values.

### Additional information

Sort / selector function:

```
const getFilteredVenues = (venues, { sortBy }) => {
  return venues.sort((a, b) => {
    if (sortBy === "alfabetical") {
      return a.venue_name.toLowerCase() > b.venue_name.toLowerCase();
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
};
```

- Redux version: ^3.7.2
- React version: 16.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` does inplace array modification. Just make a copy.

```
const getFilteredVenues = (venues, { sortBy }) => {
  return venues.slice(0).sort((a, b) => {
    if (sortBy === "alfabetical") {
      return a.venue_name.toLowerCase() > b.venue_name.toLowerCase();
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Hey man, I implemented this same functionality in an other webapp. Exact same setup. So it supposed to work. It;s just the render function which is not being re-rendered. The componentDidReceiveNewProps does not receive any. But the mapStateToProps of redux is being called with the new values. :0

Comment: @KevinVugts Nevertheless, your selector mutates global state. So you have to make a copy. :) Just give it a try.

Comment: Is it bad practise that I mutate the global state in the mapStateToProps?

Comment: @YuryTarbanko have a look at this paste bin: https://pastebin.com/FfaKJrHL is the filter function in javascript making a copy like you do with your slices(0) ?

Comment: "Is it bad practise" - absolutely. In the later setup `filter` creates new array, so you don't need `slice`.

Comment: What would you recommend me to do in order to filter / sort the array - redux store in a good way?

Comment: @KevinVugts `filter + sort` is ok. If you only sort then you need to make copy (for ex `[...venues].sort()`. Plus use `reselect` module for memoization.

Comment: If you're copying the array on every selector call it's gonna **recompute on every action dispatch** - even if the action doesn't change this part of the store. As a result new object is passed via props and rerender will be called on connected component.
To avoid this you should memoize your selector output, e.g. with `reselect`, `lodash` or own memoization mechanism.